# Using Naive Bayes to calculate the probability of user presence based on the presence of her belongings

Tags: conditional-probability, bayes

Alice, Bob, and Charlie work for a company and each of them has a cell phone and a car. They drive to work and they have their cell phones with them when they show up at work.

The company has installed some sensors to detect the presence of the cars and cell phones. Sometimes our users use the public transportation to work or they may forget their cell phones at home. At the same time, they may leave their cell phone behind at work or use public transportation to go home.

We interviewed the users for their habits and they say with a certain probability they are where their belongings are. I would call these probabilities P(user | belonging) which are shown in the parentheses in front of each item.

Alice – iPhone (99%), Honda (90%)

Bob – Blackberry (98%), Ford (95%)

Charlie – Samsung (99%), Jeep (98%)

Alice is an early bird and 99% of the time, she is at work by 9:00 AM (P(Alice)=0.99). Bob usually works between 9:00 AM to 5:00 PM but he is occasionally late. We can say 80% of the time he is in the office by 9:00 AM (P(Bob)=0.8). Charlie is fashionably late and only 10 percent of the time he is in the office by 9:00 AM (P(Charlie)=0.10).

The sensors have created a database of historical information about presence of each item over time. So by 9:00 AM, the chance of each item being at the office is:

P(iPhone)=98% - P(Honda)=91%

P(Blackberry)=82% - P(Ford)=75%

P(Samsung)=9% - P(Jeep)=10%

So we want to know if Charlie’s car and cell phone are both detected by the sensors at 9:00 AM, what the probability of Charlie being at the office is.

Based on Naïve Bayes:

P(Charlie|Samsung,Jeep) = (P(Charlie) * P(Samsung|Charlie)*P(Jeep|Charlie))/(((P(Charlie) * (P(Samsung|Charlie) * P(Jeep|Charlie))+ (P(~Charlie) * (P(Samsung|~Charlie)*P(Jeep|~Charlie)))

We can calculate:

P(Samsung|Charlie) = P(Charlie|Samsung)*P(Samsung)/P(Charlie) = 0.99 * 0.09/0.1= 0.891

P(Samsung|~Charlie) = (1-P(Charlie|Samsung))*P(Samsung)/P(~Charlie) = 0.01 * 0.09/0.9 = 0.001

P(Jeep|Charlie) = P(Charlie|Jeep)*P(Jeep)/P(Charlie) = 0.98 * 0.10 /0.1 = 0.98

P(Jeep|~Charlie) = (1- P(Charlie|Jeep))*P(Jeep)/P(~Charlie) = 0.02 * 0.10/0.9 = 0.002

P(Charlie|Samsung,Jeep) = 0.1 *(0.891*0.98) /(0.1*(0.891*0.98))+(0.9*(0.001*0.002))) = 0.087318/(0.087318+0.0000018) = 0.999

Now, I have 2 questions:

1- Is this math correct?

2- If the prior probability of Jeep goes from 0.1 to 0.11(or higher), P(Jeep|Charlie) becomes 1.078(or higher). What is wrong now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1$. Say we write $C$ for Charlie being at work, $S$ for his phone being there, and $J$ for his car being there. You've written $P(C|S,J) = \frac{P(C)P(S|C)P(J|C)}{P(S,J)}$. In general, it is really $P(C|S,J) = \frac{P(C)P(S|C)P(J|C,S)}{P(S,J)},$ unless you assume that $P(J|C,S)=P(J|C)$, i.e. that the chance of Charlie's belongings being at work are independent of each other. We don't have any information on how the presence of a belonging affects the chance of the other being present, so we don't have enough information to calculate $P(C|S,J)$ at all!

Still, let's see what happens if we assume they're independent. In this case I'd say your answer is roughly correct, with some inaccuracy coming from approximating $P(J|\textrm{not } C) = \frac{2}{9}$ as $0.02$. Using the exact number instead, I calculate $P(C|S,J)=\frac{87318}{87318+20} = \frac{87318}{87338}=0.999771$.

$2$. We know that $P(C,J)=P(J)P(C|J)=\frac{98}{100}P(J)$. On the other hand, $P(C)=\frac{10}{100}$. This means that our values of $P(C|J)$ and $P(C)$ put limits on how probable seeing $J$ can be, because $P(C,J)>P(C)$ would mean we are more likely to see both Charlie and his car at work than we are to see Charlie at work, regardless of where his car is. This would be absurd. What goes wrong with your example here is that the new value of $P(J)$ is higher than this imposed limit, so in practice we would simply never see this combination of three probabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I assume chance of Charlie's belongings being at work are independent of each other and I think it is a correct assumption. If I don't drive to work, I may take my umbrella with me but I don't think twice about taking my cell phone with me. So I would say umbrella and car are dependent but both are independent from cell phone.

Comment: On the second note, I got your point and it makes sense. My follow up question might be very silly: But let's say we are dealing with a real system that makes decision based on these inputs. P(J)=0.1 or P(J)=0.11 could be in the system's margin of error. What is the best course of action here? (1) truncate P(J|C) to one, (2) adjust P(C|J) so P(C,J)<P(C), or (3) ignore the P(J) and just go with P(S).

Comment: When you say margin of error, do you mean floating-point error, or error in the original observations? It would be a shame to take option (3) and throw away so much information just because of floating-point error. I'm not sure what to choose between (1) and (2), though. If the error is in the original observations, it depends on where you believe the error to be, and how it behaves. That would require a hierarchical Bayes model, which might be more complicated than you'd want.

Comment: Now that I look at it again, the other thing to consider is that your values for P(user|belonging) were obtained from asking the employees what they believed the probabilities to be, which probably won't be correct. So you might want to take some observations to check your value for P(C|J), especially if you're getting situations where calculated probabilities are larger than one.

Comment: Thanks! I think using the user's guestimates would be good to bootstrap the process but I need some additional sensors to detect the presence of the users. Something like password entry attempts, web browsing logs, and calendar entries would help me to conclude P(user) and P(user|belonging).

Comment: @user37577 That's the sort of thing you'd need to calibrate the probabilities. I'm guessing, though, that sensors of the type you mentioned aren't perfectly accurate? Otherwise you could just set up those sensors for user presence, and avoid all of this statistical inference in the first place! So you'd also need to account for possible inaccuracies from those sensors. I'd suggest the alternative of manually checking for the presence of the users at 9am for a few days, if that's possible, because it would be a reliable sample.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not having a problem with Naive Bayes, but with Bayes' rule itself? Let's forget about the phones, forget about Alice and Bob. That simplifies your question to:

given $P(C|J)=98%$, $P(J)=10%$, calculate $P(J|C)$. If you want to apply Bayes' rule here, you cannot use the value of $P(C)=10%$ that you have given, but you have to calculate it: $P(C)=P(C&J)+P(C&~J)=P(C|J)*P(J)+P(C|~J)*P(~J)$.

However, you haven't given $P(C|~J)$. Is it supposed to be equal to $P(~C|J)$? I.e. the probability he leaves the car at work when going home is the same that he leaves the car at home when coming to work?

Comment: Why can't you use the value of $P(C)$ that's given?