# Bayes method on the probability of an object drawn at random using percentages

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

It's the normal Bayes equation but I'm not sure if I've calculated this correctly or how to check my work, [here is](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82867/using-naive-bayes-to-calculate-the-probability-of-user-presence-based-on-the-pre) a somewhat similar question but I wasn't sure if our math was the same, the question was a little more complex, **here's my question:**

*A company has four machines that manufacture levers for cars, machines M1, M2, M3 and M4 manufactures 10%, 25%, 25% and 40% of the levers respectively. Of their outputs 10,15,20,and 2 percent respectively are defective levers. You draw a lever at random during inspection from the product bin and you find it to be defective. What is the probability that it was manufactured by machine M2? Derive the **Bayes** (not Naive Bayes) formulation from the conditional probability after listening to the lecture.*

Here's my work:

```
m1 = 10%; defective output 10%
m2 = 25%; defective output 15%
m3 = 25%; defective output 20%
m4 = 40%; defective output 2%
```

```
m1 = 1/10; 1/10 defective
m2 = 1/4; 3/20 defective
m3 = 1/4; 1/5 defective
m4 = 2/5; 1/50 defective
```

```
  1/4  * [(3/20)/(1/4)]
------------------------
+ 1/10 * [(1/10)/(1/10)]
+ 1/4  * [(3/20)/(1/4)]
+ 1/4  * [(1/5)/(1/4)]
+ 2/5  * [(1/50)/(2/5)]
```

```
  .25  * [(.15)/(.25)]
------------------------
+ .10  * [(.10)/(.10)]
+ .25  * [(.15)/(.25)]
+ .25  * [(.2)/(.25)]
+ .40  * [(.02)/(.40)]
```

```
.15
-----
.10+.15+.2+.02
```

```
.15
-----
0.47
```

```
15/47 = 0.319148936
~32%
```

This is the example in the textbook I'm basing my work on, I've highlighted some things for clarity, the example doesn't use percentages and is more simplified:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The question was answered **[here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/103296/bayes-theorem-on-the-probability-of-an-object-drawn-at-random-using-percentages)** I wasn't sure if this was better for the statistics community or data science.